# Output Cache ASP .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Estou estudando sobre o output cache no Asp .NET MVC para melhorar o desempenho da minha aplicação. Pelo que vi ele pode ser armazenado em vários lugares como:

```
· Any
· Client
· Downstream
· Server
· None
· ServerAndClient
```

**Dúvida**

Caso eu faça o cache de uma página, **quando usar cada uma das situações?** Não encontrei nenhum lugar onde explique qual a diferença do armazenamento entre elas.

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Acho que [neste site](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) voce consegue encontrar maiores referencias.

Comment: Neste site apenas explica onde é armazenado cada um, eu gostaria de saber quando usar cada uma delas e por que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na maioria das vezes o cache Any vai atender a expectativa, pois ele realiza o cache Local/Proxy/Server.

Se você tem um ecommerce e ele possui uma página de categorias, onde o usuario selecionará qual a categoria ele deseja acessar.

Este tipo de informação pode ser "cacheada" em qualquer lugar, quando o usuario tentar acessar e ele tem os arquivos na propria maquina, vai apenas fazer uma requisição HEAD no server e se o cache estiver valido ele responde com os dados que está na maquina local, se um usuario que nunca acessou o seu sistema tentar acessar, ele vai utilizar o cache da ultima requisição.

---

Você não deve realizar o cache de informações sensiveis no server/proxy, veja a seguinte situação:

```
  [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Olá " + User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

Se o usuario Cesar realizar a requisição, vai retornar normalmente "Olá Cesar", porém, quando o José realizar a requisição após o Cesar, vai retornar a informação "Olá Cesar".

---

Relacionado ao cache local, se voce precisar de uma atualização completa na página, e inviabilizar o acesso à pagina antiga, você precisaria alterar o endereço do seu site, para que o usuario realize a requisição e não utilize o cache local.

Ref: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659831/where-to-cache-in-asp-net-mvc-5-server-or-client) [link 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) [link 3](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)